# unable to send response in expect command

Tags: shell, expect

I'm running below command and I'm also sending response using send but its not taking any input. kindly tell me where I'm missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set server_ip "<server?"

spawn ssh -A $server_ip

expect {
    "*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*" {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW):*" {
        send "JIRA\r"
    }
}

interact
```

ran `expect -d script`
output:

```
sri@Sreekanth ~ % expect -d jira 
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = jira  
set argc 0
set argv0 "jira"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file jira
spawn ssh -A <server>
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {43449}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*"? no
"*Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW):*"? no
Warning: Permanently added '<server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

expect: does "Warning: Permanently added '<server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Warning: Permanently added '[<server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Warning: Permanently added '[<server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n"
send: sending "yes\r" to { exp6 }
expect: continuing expect

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*"? no
"*Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW):*"? no
yes

expect: does "yes\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*"? no
"*Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW):*"? no
Warning: Permanently added '<server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

expect: does "yes\r\nWarning: Permanently added '<server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "yes\r\nWarning: Permanently added '<server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "yes\r\nWarning: Permanently added '<server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n"
send: sending "yes\r" to { exp6 }
expect: continuing expect

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*"? no
"*Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW):*"? no
yes

expect: does "yes\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*"? no
"*Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW):*"? no
yes
yes

expect: does "yes\r\nyes\r\nyes\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*"? no
"*Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW):*"? no
expect: timed out
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp6 sent <Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW): >
Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW): spawn id exp6 sent <Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW): >
Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW): spawn id exp6 sent <Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW): >
Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW):
```

Comment: If you ssh manually, without doing anything else, do you see either of those 2 lines?

Comment: run your script with `expect -d scriptname` and paste the output.

Comment: @glennjackman i've updated in the query section please check

Comment: That debug output does not correspond to the code you previously added. The pattern `"*Enter JIRA ticket:*"` is not in your code.

Comment: @glennjackman sorry i ran wrong script, updated but issue still same

Comment: The pattern `*(RSA) to the list of known hosts.*` is matching the text `Warning: Permanently added '<server>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.` -- that's not a question so you shouldn't be sending "yes" at that point. You'll need to make your patterns more specific.

Comment: warning related prompts actually its not expecting anything but just passing yes, even if dont send any input even that works actually the issue at "*Ticketing system (JIRA or SNOW):*" we have to send JIRA input, i tried few things but not working anyway

Comment: @glennjackman any help plz